# Rails 4, Devise - Cannot update username from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 with devise for user authentication.

I have problem with creating user from console nor from edited devise registration view. I can set password and email, but i can't set username, I have to create user witouth name and then change it from dbconsole using SQL command ("UPDATE users SET..."). Then I can login with username.

My users table:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name",                default: "", null: false
    t.string   "email",               default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",  default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",       default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
end
```

My users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates_presence_of :name, :email, :password
  attr_accessor :name   
end
```

When I try

```
u = User.new
u.name = "test"
```

from rails console *name* stays blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove this line:

```
  attr_accessor :name
```

Comment: `attr_accessor` is a Ruby method for defining accessors to your instance variables. Rails (prior to 4.0) has `attr_accessible` method for parameter protection. They're mixed up very often. When you call `attr_accessor` you screw up Rails accessors for your fields.

Comment: Basically, `ActiveRecord` magically defines getter/setter methods for the columns in your database. When you do `attr_accessor :name`, you override those with regular ruby getter/setter methods that just get/set an instance variable `@name`, which has no association with the database field.